# Finite difference method for DEq's of form dy/dx = f(x,y)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, finite-differences

I was watching a math tutorial on the finite difference method that
stated that the method could be used for ODEs of the form:

$dy/dx = f(x) + g(y)$

but not for equations where the function is a function of both x and
y.  In other words, if the x's and y's can be separated, we can use the
finite difference method, but not if they are multiplied together in any way.

Is this a restriction?  And if so, why?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the method the tutorial was teaching? From the sound of it it could be the Euler method, the midpoint method or a trapezoidal method.

Comment: In the example, the presenter uses a forward Euler, though he didn't specify that the restriction (the variable separability requirement) was specific to Euler or other methods.